# R-Box not working with Sublime Text 3

Tags: r, sublimetext3

I have been running R from ST3, but all of a sudden it has stopped working and I cannot figure out why. When I open a R-file in ST3, R does not open after hitting [Cmd + enter]. I have already tried the following things:

1) Check if the path to Rgui is correct in the User settings (it is).
2) Check if the file is in R-extended format (it is).

I have reinstalled ST3, but the problem is still there. I am running ST3 on Windows 7 (64-bit).

In the command-line I get the following error:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 818, in run_
    return self.run(edit) 
  File "SendText in C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\SendText.sublime-package", line 89, in run

  File "SendText in C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\SendText.sublime-package", line 27, in send
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 819, in __init__
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1110, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1104, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this issue?